# How to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{2007}_{0}e^{\frac{x^{2008}}{n}}dx$?

Tags: integration, limits

How to calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^{2007}_{0}e^{\frac{x^{2008}}{n}}dx?$$ Can I just write $e^{\frac{x^{2008}}{n}} \rightarrow e^0$ when $n \to \infty$?

Comment: As the limiting condition is independent of $x$ , I think you can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{0}^{2007}e^{x^{2008}/n}dx\leq\int_{0}^{2007}e^{x^{2008}}dx\leq2007e^{2007^{2008}}
 $$ so by the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{2007}e^{x^{2008}/n}dx=\int_{0}^{2007}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{x^{2008}/n}dx=2007.$$

Comment: Nice solution by using application above theorem! But in DCT we deal with measurable functions, but here integrands are continuous. Can you explain it please since i knew this theorem couple weeks ago.

Comment: @RFZ A continuous function is measurable.

Comment: Over what sigma algebra?

Comment: @RFZ In $\mathbb{R}$ with its Borel $\sigma$ algebra every continuous function is misurable. For more details see http://www.applebaum.staff.shef.ac.uk/Ch2MeasFn.pdf

Comment: Thanks for link. But in general case continuous function is not measurable right?

Comment: @RFZ A continuous function from two Borel space is measurable, but the contrary is not true.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&
2007 <
\int_{0}^{2007}\exp\pars{x^{2008} \over n}\,\dd x < 2007\exp\pars{2007^{2008} \over n}
\\[3mm]
&\imp\quad\color{#f00}{%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2007}\exp\pars{x^{2008} \over n}\,\dd x} =
\color{#f00}{2007}
\end{align}

Comment: perfect use of squeeze.+1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. Here, we call it "sandwich theorem".

Comment: When I studied calculus long back I also found the name "Sandwich theorem" in my textbooks. I came to know about the name "Squeeze theorem" only a few years ago and that too from math.stackexchange.com. This term appears to have gained more popularity.

Answer (score 1):

We note that  $$e^{x^{2007}/n}= 1+ \frac{x^{2007}}{n}+ \frac{x^{4014}}{2n^2}+\dotsb $$ Since this series converges uniformly we can integrate term by term and we get that
$$\int_{0}^{2007} e^{x^{2007}/n}\, dx= \int_{0}^{2007}1 \, dx+ \int_{0}^{2007}\frac{x^{2007}}{n}\, dx+ \int_{0}^{2007}\frac{x^{4014}}{2n^2}\, dx+\dotsb $$  Letting $n$ go to infinity we see that all integrals except the first vanish in the limit. The result is  $2007$.

Comment: but I am getting 1 plugging in $n=\infty$

Comment: Sorry but this raises more convergence problems (and leaves them unsolved) than needed.